# Windows 10 Search API

Tags: windows, search, microsoft-metro, windows-10, cortana

I'd like users to be able to type a product id into the Windows 10 search box and have it show a list of products from a network database, then when they click on that product id, have it load a web page from our intranet.  Is this possible?  Would I need to have a desktop application that sits on the computer for Cortana to search?

Comment: Cortana can only start desktop applications, not interact with them. So you would have to write a UWP Application do use Cortana for that Task.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UWP app with a VCD file where you need to set how Cortana can call your app. Lat's say your app is called "find it" or what ever, you can then tell cortana that whenever some one says or types "find it" on its search box "she" must call your app with whats after the "find it" as a parameter.

```
        if (eventObject.detail.kind === Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.ActivationKind.voiceCommand) {
        var speechRecognitionResult = eventObject.detail.result;

        // Get the name of the voice command. 
        // For this example, we declare only one command.
        var voiceCommandName = speechRecognitionResult.rulePath[0];

        // Get the actual text spoken.
        var textSpoken = speechRecognitionResult.text !== undefined ? speechRecognitionResult.text : "EXCEPTION";
```